# How to handle 4TBs of data in mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, sharding

I am trying to insert data in mongoDB using scripts but the data size becomes 4TBs. If I start using shards the merging and spliting process becomes heavier. My shard key is timestamp generated from objectID.

Please comment if I am doing things right.

Answer (score 0):

That is a drawback of using a [monotonically-increasing field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/hashed-sharding/#monotonically-changing-shard-keys) (such as a timestamp or ObjectId) in your shard key. All the data will be initially written to a single shard (the one with the last chunk), and the balancer will have to work very hard at splitting the chunk and migrating the data to other shards.

There are two workarounds available to you:

1. Change to use [hashed sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/hashed-sharding/) instead of conventional ranged sharding; that will distribute the inserts across the different shards more evenly.
2. Design a different shard key.